# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable DBSCAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, dbscan

Hi I want to make the outlier of an image into black color using dbscan but It gave me `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` below is the code. error line **if (clusters[a][aa] == -1):**

```
#retrieving the length and the breadth of the image
length = len(img)
breadth = len(img[0])
if (isdbscan):
    print("Number of clusters = ",maxclus)
    for a in range(0,length):
        for aa in range(0,breadth):
            #here we want to change all the outliners to black color  
            if (clusters[a][aa] == -1):
                img[a][aa][0]= 0
                img[a][aa][1]= 0
                img[a][aa][2]= 0
    for z in range(0,maxclus):
        #we randomly try to select the colors for the clusters 
        b = random.sample(range(0,255),1)
        bb = random.sample(range(0,255),1)
        bbb = random.sample(range(0,255),1)
        for a in range(0,length):
            for aa in range(0,breadth):
                if (clusters[a][aa] == z+1):
                    img[a][aa][0]= b[0]
                    img[a][aa][1]= bb[0]
                    img[a][aa][2]= bbb[0]
```

DBSCAN.py here in this part I'm making clusters and the rest of calculation. I went though some websites like towardsdatascince and some other all of them putting -1 to make the outliers black

```
import numpy as np
def mDBSCAN(fun,dataset,eps,minpts):
    #first for better processing, we can leverage the numpy array 
    dbscan_dataset_array = dataset
    #length and breadth of image
    length = len(dbscan_dataset_array)
    breadth = len(dbscan_dataset_array[0])

#create a list 
clusterlabels = np.array([[[0 for x in range(1)] for y in range(breadth)] for z in range(length)])
c = 0

#to determine core objs from dataset
for p in range(0,length):
    for pp in range(0,breadth):
        #if the obj was not visited
        if (clusterlabels[p][pp] == 0):                 
            neighbours_of_p = checkNeighbours(fun,dbscan_dataset_array,p,pp,eps)
            #following condition is for determining the p if a core-obj, if yes, we expand our cluster
           
            if ((len(neighbours_of_p[0]))/2 >= minpts): 
                c += 1 #a new cluster is found
                #assign clusterlabel of seed to current cluster
                clusterlabels[p][pp] = c 
                #this does not make a copy of neighbours_of_p list but references it as seeds
                seeds = neighbours_of_p 
                expandCluster(fun,dbscan_dataset_array,seeds,clusterlabels,c,eps,minpts)
            #if the number of neighbours are less than the given minpts then it is a outlier    
            else: 
                clusterlabels[p][pp] = -1 
return c,clusterlabels



def checkNeighbours(fan,dbscan_dataset_array,p,pp,eps):
#list to store neighbours
neighbours=[[]]
#run through dataset to find neighbours of p
for q in range(0,len(dbscan_dataset_array)):
    for qq in range(0,len(dbscan_dataset_array[0])): 
        
        #To avoid redundant euclidean distance calculation for the same position we can leverage from below condition
        if (q==p)and (qq==pp):
            continue
        if (fan == 1):
            if (np.linalg.norm((dbscan_dataset_array[p][pp] - dbscan_dataset_array[q][qq])) <= eps): #calculate L1 norm 
                neighbours[0].extend([q,qq])
        if (fan == 2):
            if (np.linalg.norm((dbscan_dataset_array[p][pp] - dbscan_dataset_array[q][qq]),1) <= eps): #calculate L1 norm
                neighbours[0].extend([q,qq])
return neighbours


def expandCluster(fan,dbscan_dataset_array,seeds,clusterlabels,c,eps,minpts):
#run through seeds list till is empty
while (len(seeds[0])>0): 
        currentseedp = seeds[0][0]
        #take first seed as current seed
        currentseedpp = seeds[0][1] 
        if (clusterlabels[currentseedp][currentseedpp] == -1): #we already know it doesnt have enough neighbours
            clusterlabels[currentseedp][currentseedpp] = c #claim it as leaf point of the current cluster
        elif (clusterlabels[currentseedp][currentseedpp] == 0): #if seed is not already claimed by another cluster or is noise
            clusterlabels[currentseedp][currentseedpp] = c #assign current seed the current cluster id
            #once we have our seeds now, we can find core objs if we can expand our cluster, if the points that are density-reachable belongs to same cluster
            neighbours_of_seed = checkNeighbours(fan,dbscan_dataset_array,currentseedp,currentseedpp,eps)
            #we were finding the neighbours of a neighbour of the current seed 
            if ((len(neighbours_of_seed))/2 >= minpts): #then dbscan_dataset_array[currentseed] is a core object 
                seeds[0].extend(neighbours_of_seed[0])
        del(seeds[0][0])
        del(seeds[0][0])#remove current seed from seeds list
```

Comment: Can you share how `clusters` is created/initiazlied?

Comment: please check the code again.